# Extract value from structure within an array of arrays in spark using scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading json data into spark data frame using scala.
The schema is as follows:

```
 root
 |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- playerId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sources: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- matchId: long (nullable = true)
```

The data looks as follows:

```
{ "metadata" : [ { "playerId" : "1234", "sources" : [ { "matchId": 1 } ] }, { "playerId": "1235", "sources": [ { "matchId": 1 } ] } ] }
{ "metadata" : [ { "playerId" : "1234", "sources" : [ { "matchId": 2 } ] }, { "playerId": "1248", "sources": [ { "score": 12.2 , "matchId": 1 } ] } ] }
{ "metadata" : [ { "playerId" : "1234", "sources" : [ { "matchId": 3 } ] }, { "playerId": "1248", "sources": [ { "matchId": 3 } ] } ] }
```

The goal is to find if playerId is 1234 and matchId is 1, then return isPlayed as true. The structure of sources is not fixed. There might be fields other than matchId.

I wrote a udf considering metadata to be of type WrappedArray[String] and am able to read the playerId column

```
def hasPlayer = udf((metadata: WrappedArray[String], playerId: String) => { 
  metadata.contains(playerId)
  })

df.withColumn("hasPlayer", hasPlayer(col("metadata"), col("superPlayerId")))
```

But I am not able to figure out how to query the matchId field given playerId. I tried reading the field as WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Long]] but it gives a typecasting exception in withColumn on metadata.sources.matchId column.

I am relatively new to Spark. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with JSON, get to know the built-in function `explode`, which turns a single cell containing a `WrappedArray` into multiple rows representing the structs inside. I think it helps here (twice):

```
df.select(explode($"metadata").as("metadata"))
  .select($"metadata.playerId", explode($"metadata.sources.matchId").as("matchId"))
  .filter($"matchId".equalTo(1))
  .select($"matchId", lit(true).as("isPlayed"))
```

Basically I use `explode` to create multiple rows (and rename to something convenient), navigate the object tree to the JSON fields I want, repeat the `explode`/rename process for the `matchId`, and filter out everything that isn't `1` This allows me finally to use the `lit` function to "hardcode" values of `true` for a brand new column called `isPlayed` since everything that isn't `1` is gone.

If this isn't exactly what you're looking for, hopefully it gives you some pointers. The `functions` [library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) can be very helpful to you as you get to know Spark.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Would this be a costly operation? Also is there a way by which I could preserve the count of rows. Explode I think would multiply each row by number of exploded elements from array 1 * number of exploded elements from array 2. Would joining back this data with the original table be efficient?

Comment: It uses all the higher-level Spark functionality, which is something one should do as much as possible to allow Catalyst to optimize things. But why don't you just try it to see if it is "efficient"?