# transformation of spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I had a `DataFrame` and here's the schema. Numbers of `element` is unknown but some of the elements(for example `element1` and `element3`) must exist and uniqueness

```
root
 |-- context: struct (nullable = true)
 |---|-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |   |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |   |    |-- dimensions: array (nullable = true)
 |   |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |   |    |    |    |-- element1: string (nullable = true)
 |   |    |    |    |-- element2: string (nullable = true)
 |   |    |    |    |-- element3: string (nullable = true)
 |   |    |    |    |-- ***     : string (nullable = true)
 |   |    |    |    |-- elementN: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I transform it to schema like this?

```
root
 |-- context: struct (nullable = true)
 |---|-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |---|-- element1: string (nullable = true)
 |---|-- element3: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the `explode` function. These are following links, please go through them.

[Extract columns in nested Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070859/extract-columns-in-nested-spark-dataframe)

[Extract value from structure within an array of arrays in spark using scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424554/extract-value-from-structure-within-an-array-of-arrays-in-spark-using-scala)